# android : sqlite using parameter binding for LIKE

Tags: android, sqlite, binding

My query looks something similar to COL1 = ? AND COL2 LIKE ?
OR COL3 LIKE ? OR COL4 LIKE ? ..

and i pass the values of selection args as {"col1value","searchstring",
"searchstring","searchstring"}

I am comparing if col2, 3 and 4 with same string . 
So can i optimize using binding to something like
COL1 = ? AND COL2 LIKE ?2
OR COL3 LIKE ?2 OR COL4 LIKE ?2

so that i dont have to repeat the string in arguments 
{"col1value","searchstring"}

Is this possible and if yes what is the right syntax for it.

Comment: Look to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45284986/7341528
It is more better 
http://prntscr.com/fzps8d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [many ways of specifying parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam). To (re-)use a specific parameter number, append the number to the `?`:

```
COL1 = ?1 AND (COL2 LIKE ?2 OR COL3 LIKE ?2 OR COL4 LIKE ?2)
```

(And AND has higher precedence than OR.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to this 
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE searchstring IN(COL2, COL3, COL4);

In android select :

```
String select = "? IN (COL2, COL3, COL4)"
```

select args :

```
String[] args = new String[] {"searchstring"};
```